# How to find a gutenberg block by blockName if blocks are nested (recursively)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I need to get some data from an ACF Gutenberg block, but it is nested in a nested block, so

```
<?php
$blocks = parse_blocks( $pid->post_content );
foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
    if ( $block['blockName'] === 'acf/your-block-name' ) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a recursive function. The code will look like:

```
<?php
$blocks = parse_blocks($pid->post_content);
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $myAcfBlock = getMyAcfBlock($block);
    if($myAcfBlock){
        //do something
    }
}

function getMyAcfBlock($blockObject)
{
    if ($blockObject['blockName'] === 'acf/your-block-name') {
        return $blockObject;
    }
    if (!empty($blockObject['innerBlocks'])) {
        foreach ($blockObject['innerBlocks'] as $innerBlock) {
            $innerBlockObject = getLandigFormBlock($innerBlock);
            if ($innerBlockObject) {
                return $innerBlockObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```